# AJAX in plugin wp_send_json() sending html

Tags: plugins, ajax, json

I wrote a plugin that calls a PHP function from JQuery and the php sends a json response back to the Jquery using `wp_send_json()`.  The functions are all called successfully, but the json request sends a lot of html to the jquery function every time.  How do I make the json sent by the php function only a specific message?

JQUERY:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {

        jQuery( 'body' ).on( 'click', '.wpm_mail_link', function( e ) {

            var varData = 'name:foobar&email=bar@baz.foo';      

      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        action: "wp_ajax_send_email",
        url: my_ajax_obj.ajax_url,
        data: varData,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log('Ajax request successful');
          console.log(data.message);
        }
      });



        });

});
```

PHP:

```
    public function send_email() {
        $response = array(
        'message' => 'Sent',
        'ID'      => 1,
    );

    wp_send_json( $response );
    }
```

Comment: Everything looks right to me. There might be something else going on that has nothing to do with this code, but is conflicting with it.

Comment: the PHP function IS called by the Ajax request so idk... oh and I did remember to add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_email', [ $this, 'send_email' ] ); and add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_send_email', [ $this, 'send_email' ] ); so that it would all work.  I have used AJAX successfully in OOP before, so I don't think it's related to that but I just don't know...

Comment: Does your button also do something else? Try `e.preventDefault()` in your click function in js.

Comment: Have you tried specifying dataType: 'json' in your Ajax call?

Comment: ok my wordpress installation started showing new errors tonight which led to me commenting out some unrelated lines that was using JQuery... anyway, now the function is printing 'undefined' instead of that big block of html from before... does that give any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! I was getting a false positive with the ajax request.  I thought it was going through but returning 'undefined' but I was actually using the wrong url.